# SQL Left Outer Join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables name called chemical_inventory and chemical_issue

chemical_inventory table values are

```
chemical_no| chemical_name| quantity | dat
----------------------------------------------------
1          | 2BL          |     5    | 2015-01-22
1          | 2BL          |    15    | 2015-01-27
2          | Acitic Acid  |    10    | 2015-01-27
2          | Acitic Acid  |    15    | 2015-01-27
3          | Acton        |    10    | 2015-01-27
3          | Acton        |    32    | 2014-12-27
3          | Acton        |    10    | 2014-12-26
1          | 2BL          |     5    | 2015-01-29
```

chemical_issue table values are

```
chemical_no| chemical_name| issue_qty| issue_date
1          |  2BL         |  10.000  | 2015-01-22
1          |  2BL         |  15.000  | 2015-01-25
2          |  Acitic Acid |  13.000  | 2015-01-22
2          |  Acitic Acid |  14.000  | 2015-01-29
3          |  Acton       |  8.000   | 2015-01-22
3          |  Acton       |  11.00   | 2014-01-29
```

I want to get this output result

```
chemical_no| chemical_name| openingQty| purchaseQty| Issue
1          |  2BL         |  25       |     0      |  25.000
2          |  Acitic Acid |  25       |     0      |  27.000
3          |  Acton       |  10       |     42     |  19.000
```

But I am getting this wrong output while using the below query

```
chemical_no| chemical_name| openingQty| purchaseQty|   Issue
1          | 2BL          |  50       |   0        |    75.000
2          | Acitic Acid  |  50       |    0       |    54.000
3          | Acton        |  20       |   84       |    57.000
```

Query used:

```
select
    chemical_inventory.chemical_no,
    chemical_inventory.chemical_name,
    Sum(Case 
           When chemical_inventory.dat >= '2015-01-01' 
             And chemical_inventory.dat <= '2015-01-30' 
           Then chemical_inventory.quantity 
           Else 0 
        End) as openingQty,
    Sum(Case 
          When chemical_inventory.dat < '2015-01-01' 
               Or chemical_inventory.dat > '2015-01-30' 
          Then chemical_inventory.quantity 
          Else 0 
       End) as purchaseQty,
   SUM(case 
         When chemical_issue.issue_date >= '2015-01-01' 
              or chemical_issue.issue_date <= '2015-01-30' 
         Then chemical_issue.issue_qty 
         Else 0 
       End) as Issue 
from 
    chemical_inventory 
left join 
    chemical_issue on chemical_inventory.chemical_no = chemical_issue.chemical_no 
group by 
    chemical_inventory.chemical_name, chemical_inventory.chemical_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is query to get the result you want

```
  DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
    ChemicalNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    quantity  NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    date NVARCHAR(MAX)
  )
  DECLARE @tt TABLE
  ( 
    ChemicalNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    issuequantity  NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    issuedate NVARCHAR(MAX)
  )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '1', '2BL', '5','2015-01-22' ),
    ( '1', '2BL', '15','2015-01-27' ),
    ( '1', '2BL', '5','2015-01-29' ),
    ( '2', 'Acitic Acid', '10','2015-01-27' ),
    ( '2', 'Acitic Acid', '15','2015-01-27' ),
    ( '3', 'Acton', '10','2015-01-27' ),
    ( '3', 'Acton', '32','2014-12-27' ),
    ( '3', 'Acton', '10','2014-12-26' )

INSERT  INTO @tt
VALUES  ( '1', '2BL', '10','2015-01-22' ),
    ( '1', '2BL', '15','2015-01-25' ),
    ( '2', 'Acitic Acid', '13','2015-01-22' ),
    ( '2', 'Acitic Acid', '14','2015-01-29' ),
    ( '3', 'Acton', '8','2015-01-22' ),
    ( '3', 'Acton', '11','2014-01-29' )

SELECT  
  t1.ChemicalNumber,
  t1.name,
  SUM(Case 
       When t1.date >= '2015-01-01' 
         And t1.date <= '2015-01-30' 
       Then t1.quantity 
       Else 0 
    End) as openingQty,
  SUM(Case 
      When t1.date < '2015-01-01' 
           Or t1.date > '2015-01-30' 
      Then t1.quantity 
      Else 0 
    End) as purchaseQty,
  (Select SUM(CAST(t2.issuequantity AS INT)) from @tt t2 where (t2.issuedate >= '2015-01-01' 
          or t2.issuedate <= '2015-01-30') and t2.ChemicalNumber = t1.ChemicalNumber) AS IssueQuantity
FROM    @t t1
GROUP BY t1.ChemicalNumber,t1.name
```

Comment: Accept as answer if it helped you, so question can be closed.